# What is the meaning of "to head for the head"?

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of "to head for the head" in the following passage:

> Two girls went into their hotel room after spending a hot afternoon. The girls have consumed enough soda pop to fill a small barrel.
>   As the two bursting kids enter their room, they have but one thought - to head for the head.

Comment: The phrase makes no sense to me without more context.

Comment: Needs context. I can only imagine "to head for the *toilet*". Only men might use this kind of phrase though.

Comment: In the USN, in boot camp, the boots were taught to refer to the restroom as "the head". And so, to go to the head would mean to go to the restroom.

Comment: Um, @F.E. would you mind posting that as an answer, before this thing gets closed?

Answer (score 5):

It means to move to or toward the toilet.

[head](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/head)

verb (used without object)

56.

to move forward toward a point specified; direct one's course; go in a certain direction:
*to head toward town.*

noun
24.
a toilet or lavatory, especially on a boat or ship.

Comment: Thanx for explanation Jim Reynolds

Answer (score 1):

Head is maritime jargon for toilet, usually used in US civilian life by ex-Navy & Marine types who haven't yet washed the military conditioning out of their systems.  There's a whole vocabulary that serves to distinguish the in-group from the rest of the world: rack = bed or bunk, cover = hat, overhead = ceiling, etc.

Comment: Thanx for detail jamesqf